# multiprocessing multiple files in loop and store results in dictionary (python 3)

Tags: python, dictionary, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I want to execute a function in parrallel on multiple files and store the results in a dictionary with the file name as key.

But what I get from it is only `<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x7f37065fac40>` for each entry of the dictionary.

How can I get the results in each dictionary entry directly ?

Additionally I would like to monitor the progress on the overall task (how much of the files have been processed (for example a print saying file i/total).

I tried the following :

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

def process(file):
    # processings ...
    return results


pool = Pool()
result_dict = {}
for file in os.listdir("<DIRPATH>"):
    result_dict[file] = pool.apply_async(process, file)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async` method returns a `multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult` instance that represents a "future" result. That is, to get the actual result you have to call method `get` on this instance, which will block until the actual result is available and then return that result. So, you need to modify your code as follows:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

def process(file):
    # processings ...
    return results


pool = Pool()
result_dict = {}
for file in os.listdir("<DIRPATH>"):
    result_dict[file] = pool.apply_async(process, file)
for k, v in result_dict.items():
    # Update key with the actual result:
    result_dict[k] = v.get()
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

As far as your second question concerning showing progress, you must post a new question (you may not post multiple questions on a single posting that are totally unrelated). If you wish, once you have done so you may add a comment to this answer with a link to the new question and if I am able I will take a look at it.